# React.Js Input Field looses the focus on every Keystroke

Tags: reactjs

When I press a key for inputting the value, the text field loses the focus and I again need to click on the input field.

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
 import styled from "styled-components";

 import Button from "../../UI/Button/Button";
 import "./CourseInput.css";


   const CourseInput = (props) => {
   const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState("");
   const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);
```

Here is the code to handle input field changes

```
   const goalInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value.trim().length > 0) {
  setIsValid(true);
  }
  setEnteredValue(event.target.value);
    };
```

Here is the code to handle the form submission.

```
  const formSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (enteredValue.trim().length === 0) {
      setIsValid(false);
      return;
    }
    props.onAddGoal(enteredValue);
    setEnteredValue("");
  };

  const FormControl = styled.form`
     // ....some CSS
  `;


  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
      <FormControl className={!isValid && " invalid"}>
         <label>Course Goal</label>
        <input
          value={enteredValue}
          type="text"
          onChange={goalInputChangeHandler}
        />
      </FormControl>
      <Button type="submit">Add Goal</Button>
    </form>
  );
};

    export default CourseInput;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to recreate your issue locally and wasn't able to.

However, I believe the input loses focus as you are setting `isValid` to `true`, triggering a re-render and therefor input focus gets lost.

Instead of setting isValid in `goalInputChangeHandler`, leverage [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook, which will allow you to perform side effects (e.g. when changing the value of the input, a side effect is to update the `isValid` value) like below:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (enteredValue.length > 0) {
      setIsValid(true);
    } else {
      setIsValid(false);
    }
  }, [enteredValue]);

  const goalInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredValue(event.target.value);
  };
```

This also will allow you to update your submit function to be as follows:

```
  const formSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    props.onAddGoal(enteredValue);
  };
```

As the `useEffect` will ensure `isValid` is correctly updated.